# What are two lines from the Bee-Gee's song, "Don't Forget to Remember Me", in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, song-lyrics

The chorus in the Bee-Gees' haunting song, "Don't Forget to Remember Me" (1969), includes:

> "Don't forget to remember me,
> And a love that used to be"

THE FIRST LINE

To translate this into Latin: (i) the verb "to remember" = "meminisse" is defective and only exists in perfect-tense forms, hence the perfect infinitive, "meminisse". This verb selects an accusative direct object for a casual acquaintance, and a genitive for a more emotional relationship. Here, "...mei meminisse," = "...to remember me,".

(ii) The first part, is a prohibition. This can be expressed in four ways:

(a) the imperative, "ne obliviscere";

(b) the second-person of the perfect subjunctive, "ne oblitus sis";

(c) "noli" (imperative of "nolo" = "be unwilling to") plus the infinitive, "oblivisci";

(d) "cave" (take care lest) plus the present subjunctive, "obliviscaris".

Is any, of these four, more appropriate than the others?

I am choosing (b) because it looks better, giving:

> "ne oblitus sis mei meminisse"

THE SECOND LINE

In the first line "obliviscor" was behaving intransitively; here, it takes a direct object, "a/ (the one) love", and, like "meminisse" (above), it selects the genitive, "et unius amoris".

The "used to be" bit is tricky. Treating this as a relative clause, under the authority of the speaker, requiring the (imperfect) subjunctive for what was an ongoing situation, in the past, "qui esset", giving:

> "et unius amoris qui esset"

Are the two lines correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First line

According to the entry for [*oblivisci* in L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=obliviscor&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), the verb can be used with other verbs in two ways: with the infinitive (I.δ) or with a relative clause (I.ε).
The infinitive is the best fit for this purpose.

Out of the negative imperative options you list, (b) and (c) are by far the most common ones.
Negating the regular imperative with *ne* is very rare.
Your choice of (b) is a good one.

The object of *meminisse* is indeed typically the genitive of a personal pronoun.

Combining all these, your suggestion for the first line is perfect:

> *ne oblitus sis mei meminisse*

### Second line

The same predicate *oblivisci* or *meminisse* governs both lines.
You can read the English one two ways: the second line can be about (A) not forgetting the love or (B) not forgetting to remember the love.
When forgetting a thing, both the genitive and accusative work; see the entry linked above.
The same goes with *meminisse*.

On the first line I would interpret the infinitive *meminisse* as an accusative (this form is used when the verb is an object), so it would be most harmonic in reading (A) to have the object of the second line in the accusative case as well.
The genitive is certainly possible, but the switch of cases sounds a bit wonky to me.

In reading (B) you have two objects of *meminisse*, and for the same reason I would put both in the genitive case.

I think "something that used to be" is better captured in Latin by the adjective [*pristinus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=pristinus1&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
One can in principle use a relative clause, but mind you that the short relative clause "that used to be" is idiomatic in English and does not work as concisely in many other languages.

I think *et* is best replaced with *neque*.

Thus I would change the second line to:

> *nec amorem pristinum*
> OR
> *nec amoris pristini*

### Both lines

Looking at what we have, it is easy to get a simple rhyme:

> *Ne oblitus sis meminisse mei
>
> nec amoris pristini!*

You may need to insert a few syllables to make it scan; I am not familiar with the original rhythm.

Comment: What do you think of using *-que* intead of *nec*: *mei pristinique amoris*?

Comment: @TKR Can *-que* be used with negations like that? It strikes me as a little odd, but this should probably explored in a separate question. But even if it's possible, I prefer not to use it here; I get the sense that the second item is a kind of an afterthought ("oh, and don't forget this either"), but I might be misreading.

Comment: I'm not sure either, which is why I asked :) I think in this case the negation is syntactically far away enough (since *meminisse* itself is not negated) that *-que* is possible, and that it has the effect of tying together "me" and "the old love" more closely.

Comment: @TKR [I had to ask a new question about that.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/16001/79) That's a simpler version than what'd be used here, though.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Thank you.  The use of an infinitive ("meminisse") as an accusative direct-object, is a new one on me! Therefore "obliviscor" is not behaving intransitively, in the first line? In Allen & Greenough p.456: "Complementary Infinitive": "Verbs which imply another action of the same subject to complete their meaning take the infinitive without a subject accusative." Again, (A & G) p.350 makes it clear that "meminisse" + acc. (for casuals); + gen. (for relationships); therefore, the genitive must be used in the second  line. Do you agree?

Comment: @tony I think many grammars make it unnecessarily convoluted. When you need a verb as a subject ("Singing is important.") or as an object ("I like to sing."), you use the infinitive. With nouns the same roles are played by the nominative and accusative case, so I find it practically very reasonable to say that the infinitive serves as these two cases. For other cases and accusatives following a preposition, a gerund is used instead. Therefore I would indeed read *oblivisci* transitively here. But mind you that there are many ways to parse Latin grammar with wildly different terminology!

Comment: @tony Concerning the A&G reference, I don't know where you're pointing at. Page 350 (according to this [online version](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/causal-clauses)) seems to discuss something else. See the scanned page images on the right. Can you provide a link to the relevant page in that online copy of A&G?

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Your link reaches p. 539, not p. 350.

Comment: @tony That is the section number, not the page number. The book has two numberings. (It took me a while to find the correct page, as the section numbers are more visible online than the page numbers.)

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: I have the (A & G) re-write. The indices indicate that the section-numbers are (the original book's) page-numbers. When I first started referencing (A & G) I gave both section number  and the page  number, of this re-write. It began to look silly because no-one else was doing it. Now, I am advised. Thank you. Any thoughts on the genitive for the second line?

Comment: @tony It seems to me that both accusative and genitive make sense to me. The way I have seen the meanings with the two cases described, both look valid. If you want to dig deeper in to the choice of cases with *meminisse* or *oblivisci*, ask a new question. (It helps if you provide a link to an online version of the grammar. I don't have a copy of the book, and it takes a while to trace the thing. § 350 is faster to find than p. 350 but not much. Different editions can have different numberings, too. You should really learn using links!)