# Can -que be used with negation?

Tags: syntax, enclitic

If I want to negate two things, can I combine them with *-que*?
For example, if I want to say "I don't have a cat or a dog", can I say *non habeo felem canemque*?
Or should it rather be *non habeo felem canemve*?

My intuition is to say *non habeo felem nec canem* rather than *non habeo felem et canem*, but I am less sure about the enclitic.

This question arose from TKR's comment to my answer to [a recent question by tony](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/15994/79).
The case there was a little more convoluted, but I want to start with this simple setting and then ask follow-up questions if needed.

Answer (score 6):

*non habeo felem et canem* would mean "I do not have both a cat and a dog." Because -que generally behaves like et, I assume it would be interpreted identically.

Generally, when negating two elements, Latin will use a parallel structure. I would expect either:

Habeo nec/neque felem nec/neque canem

or

Non habeo (aut) felem aut canem. (Using an enclitic would not change the meaning.)

I would not say *non habeo felem nec canem*, because *nec* should be used either as an element of a pair or at the start of a new clause (combining the *et* that would serve as the clausal conjunction with the *non* of the second clause).

Comment: Thanks! Would it make sense to read it as two clauses, with the repeated *habeo* left out? I agree that *nec...nec* sounds better, but I'm not yet convinced that a single *nec* wouldn't work.

Comment: Maybe? But it’s extremely awkward. But a single nec is used when only the second element is negative. Habeo felem nec canem (I have a cat but not a dog.)